# Is there a workaround for HTC phones to push android apks during development?

Tags: android, ddms

I have a simple camera app I'm trying to push to my phone, but HTC sync (Thunderbolt on Verizon) simply will not recognize the device.  I believe this is the reason I can't get the phone to accept the APK.  All my drivers, project, and sdk manager and plugin are updated and I reinstalled HTC sync just to be sure.  I also enabled usb debugging and unknown sources

I believe the Thunderbolt connectivity issues also destabilize the eclipse plugin. I get hung randomly during Android functionality in eclipse (like simply loading DDMS or a Run Configuration).

As a result, I'm trying to find a way to work around having to use HTC sync to push my app there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I developed with a HTC Desire some weeks ago and it worked without problems.

You shouldn't need HTC sync. Have you tried to use the google usb driver as described [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html)?

Whats the output when you call `adb devices` from commandline? If everything worked correctly you should see the device id of your phone.

Sometimes the following can help if adb does not recognize your device:

- `adb kill-server` to stop the adb process
- Use the task manager to make sure no other adb process is running (stop them with the task manager)
- restart adb server by calling `adb devices`

Comment: What option should I select if I don't want to connect via HTC sync?  Charge Only, Disk Drive, Internet Connection Mode (believe this requires a subscription), Media Sync, Internet pass-through?

Comment: For HTC the dev site tells you to go to the OEM driver, which is just a link to HTC.  There you have to install HTC sync in order to get the driver.  I see "HTC BMP USB Driver" installed after I install htc sync, version 1.0.5375.  It would seem to me that is the correct driver.

Comment: I see my device listed.  It's prefixed HT and has a bunch of numbers behind it.

Comment: After I killed server and restarted device, it says device id and then "offline".  Never seen that before...

Comment: ok when it shows offline adb can connect to your device so the usb driver should work. It can help if you plug out the usb cable and then plug it in again. This often helped me when the device is shown as 'offline'.

Comment: Marking this the answer, I was able (after a bunch of retries) to push the apk to my phone on "Disk Drive" mode.  It still didn't work, but since I made progress, I think micha you helped me immensely here.  Also, ungplugging it and plugging it back it totally does the trick, DDMS lit up with my directory structure.  Still not 100% there, but much closer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the app using `adb install -r C:\path\to\app.apk`

Comment: Even after I can see my device listed in adb it just hangs...  No activity whatsoever on the Thunderbolt

Comment: If you install using adb the activity will not show, call it from launcher